# How to implement Siri/Cortana like functionality in commandline?

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to implement a small subset of siri/cortana like features in command line.

For e.g.

```
$ What is the sum of 100 and 1000
> Response: 1100
$ What is the product of 10 and 12
> Response: 120
```

The questions are predefined regular expressions. It needs to call the matching function in ruby.
Pattern: What is the sum of (\d)+ and (\d)+ 
Ruby method to call: sum(a,b)

Any pointers/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds exactly like [cucumber](http://cukes.info/), maybe take a look and see if you can just use their classes to hack something together :) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
question = gets.chomp
/\A.*(sum |product |quotient |difference )\D+([0-9]+)\D+([0-9]+).*\z/.match question
send($1, $2.to_i, $3.to_i)
```

Quick explanation for anyone that may be new to matching in Ruby:

This gets a line of input from the command line and scans it for a function name (i.e. sum, product, etc) followed by a space and potentially some non-digit characters. Then, it looks for  a first number (similarly followed by a space and 0 or more non-digit characters) and a second number followed by nothing or anything. The parentheses determine what gets assigned to the variables preceded by a `$`, i.e. the substring that matches the contents of the first set of parentheses gets assigned to $1.

Next, it calls the method whose name is the value of `$1` with the arguments (casted to integers) found in `$2` and `$3`.

Obviously, this isn't generalized at all--you're putting the method names in the regex, and it's taking a fixed number of arguments--but it'll hopefully be useful for getting you on the right track.